# Setting "params" for GET requests using RESTDataSource

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apollo, apollo-server

**Problem**: I am trying to make a GET request using `RESTDataSource`'s `get` method, but I'm receiving a `ERR_INVALID_URL` error.
**My code**:

```
async getMediaIDs() {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await this.get(`${process.env.INSTA_ID}/media`, {
        access_token: `${process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      });
    } catch(err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    return response.data.data;
  }
```

**Expected**: The request is successful, with the full url being:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{insta_id}/media?access_token={access_token}
```

**Actual**: I receive this error:

```
2019-11-15T10:03:42.974335+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: 17841402041188678/media
2019-11-15T10:03:42.974379+00:00 app[web.1]: at InstagramAPI.getMediaIDs (/app/src/data/instagram.js:17:13)
2019-11-15T10:03:42.974382+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2019-11-15T10:03:42.974395+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
2019-11-15T10:03:42.974467+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I suspect that the error is in

```
this.get(`${process.env.INSTA_ID}/media`, {
    access_token: `${process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
});
```

because I am not setting the `params` parameter correctly (*...I think. I don't know.*)

While searching for a solution, I found the `RESTDataSource` file, which leads to this:

```
protected async get<TResult = any>(
    path: string,
    params?: URLSearchParamsInit, // <----- (What I'm trying to set)
    init?: RequestInit,
  ): Promise<TResult> {
    return this.fetch<TResult>(
      Object.assign({ method: 'GET', path, params }, init),
    );
  }
```

Following `URLSearchParamsInit` leads to this:

```
export type URLSearchParamsInit =
  | URLSearchParams
  | string
  | { [key: string]: Object | Object[] | undefined }
  | Iterable<[string, Object]>
  | Array<[string, Object]>;
```

I'm not too familiar with TypeScript, but I'm guessing that those are ways to define `params?`.

Anyways, my question is **how do I set the `params` parameter for `RESTDataSource`'s `get` method**?

*side note for the Apollo devs: An API page for `RESTDataSource` would be brilliant! I would be willing to help document it, as proper documentation currently isn't available.*

Comment: What's the full stack trace for that error? Since that error gets thrown by Node itself, it's also possible you're simply providing invalid characters inside the URL string.

Comment: @DanielRearden I've added the full error log! I'll look into that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you're seeing, it doesn't look like you're setting a `baseURL`. Without the `baseURL` set, you end up with `17841402041188678/media` as the complete URL, which is not a valid URL. You can set the `baseURL` inside your RESTDataSource's constructor:

```
class InstagramAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
  }

  // ...
}
```